# Style Generated Table Rows

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to achieve this look for a table. I couldn't figure out how to space it like this. This is my code so far. How can i accomplish this?

[image]

```
      <table class="table table-inverse" data-bind="foreach: todos">         
              <tr >
                  <td ><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsDone, click: $parent.updateTodo" /></td>
                  <td ><span data-bind="text: Description"></span></td>
                  <td ><small><a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.deleteTodo" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a></small></td>
              </tr>     
      </table>
```

Comment: Use `flex-box` instead.

Comment: using flex-box will require me to use div. I cannot nest div's in my loop

Comment: Do you wants spacing between rows or you are about internal indents between table cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flex-box` to achieve this

```css
body{
  background:#3a9bcb;
}
table{
  width:100%;
}
.flex-box {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  background:#fff;
}
.col {
  flex: 1 1;
}
.col:first-child,
.col:last-child {
  flex: 0 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class=flex-box>
    <td class=col>
      <input type=checkbox>
    </td>
    <td class=col>
      Placeholder text
    </td>
    <td class=col>
      Trash
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class=flex-box>
    <td class=col>
      <input type=checkbox>
    </td>
    <td class=col>
      Placeholder text
    </td>
    <td class=col>
      Trash
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi this probably solved my issue can can i make the box white?

Comment: Updated my answer, take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can check the following snippet, if you are looking for backward compatibility the following could be useful

```css
.wrapper{padding:20px;background:blue;}
table tr td:last-child,table tr td:first-child{width:25px;}
table{width:100%;background:#fff;margin-bottom:5px}
table:last-child{margin-bottom:0;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<table class="table table-inverse" data-bind="foreach: todos">
  <tr>
    <td>[#]</td>
    <td><span data-bind="text: Description">Hello</span></td>
    <td>[#]</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="table table-inverse" data-bind="foreach: todos">
  <tr>
    <td>[#]</td>
    <td><span data-bind="text: Description">Hello</span></td>
    <td>[#]</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```